# Access every Flask array elements and Display to html with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, flask

I'm a beginner in python and flask, so i want to ask on how can i access the flask array, increments its array index and display it in html by using JavaScript. I managed to access only one of its array and display it but i failed in incrementing its index to access each of its element. Below is part of my code :

Python/Flask

```
@app.route('/Table',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def showtable():
incr1=0
incr2=0

form = InputForm2(request.form)
session['stemp'] = form.istemp.data
stemp = session['stemp']
session['etemp'] = form.ietemp.data
etemp = session['etemp']
session['stp1'] = form.istp1.data
stp1 = session['stp1']

session['spress'] = form.ispress.data
spress = session['spress']
session['epress'] = form.iepress.data
epress = session['epress']
session['stp2'] = form.istp2.data
stp2 = session['stp2']

incr1 = (etemp - stemp) / stp1
incr2 = (epress - spress) / stp2

tps = np.arange(stemp,etemp,incr1)


for i in range(0,len(tps)):
    tps[i] = tps[i].tolist()

i=0

return render_template('table.html',stemp=stemp,etemp=etemp,incr1=incr1,stp1=stp1,spress=spress,epress=epress,incr2=incr2,
                       tps=tps,i=i)
```

HTML/JavaScript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_200_200/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAfJAAAAJDIxMDc1NWExLTczODgtNDBhOS1iZmYwLWRmOTZjZjc2NzVhYQ.png">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://docs.handsontable.com/pro/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://handsontable.com/static/css/main.css">-->
    <script src="http://docs.handsontable.com/pro/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.js"></script>

    <title>Invigour Tool</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <!--<link href="dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->
    <style>

/* Move down content because we have a fixed navbar that is 50px tall */
body {
  padding-top: 50px;

}

/*
 * Global add-ons
 */

.sub-header {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

/*
 * Top navigation
 * Hide default border to remove 1px line.
 */
.navbar-fixed-top {
  border: 0;
}

/*
 * Sidebar
 */

/* Hide for mobile, show later */
.sidebar {
  display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 51px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
  }
}

/* Sidebar navigation */
.nav-sidebar {
  margin-right: -21px; /* 20px padding + 1px border */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.nav-sidebar > li > a {
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.nav-sidebar > .active > a,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:hover,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #428bca;
}

/*
 * Main content
 */

.main {
  padding: 20px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .main {
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
}
.main .page-header {
  margin-top: 0;
}

/*
 * Placeholder dashboard ideas
 */

.placeholders {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.placeholders h4 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.placeholder {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.placeholder img {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* Custom page footer */
.footer {
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-top: 2cm;
  color: #777;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;

}

.out{
    float: right;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    width: 180px;
    height: 85px;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-radius: 24px;
    background-color: limegreen;
    position: relative;
    right: 0.5cm;
    margin-top: 3cm;
}

.rest{
    float: right;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    width: 180px;
    height: 85px;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-radius: 24px;
    background-color: limegreen;
    margin-top: 6cm;
    position: relative;
    left: 4.3cm;
}

input[type="number"]{
    margin-left: 3.7cm;
}

select[id=cor4]{
    width: 165px;
}

select{
    margin-left: 1cm;
}

tr:hover{
    background-color:#f5f5f5}

    </style>
  </head>

<body>
  <div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.invigourenergy.com/">Invigour Energy</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="Menu">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="PVT Menu">PVT Tool</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>

            <li><a href="#"> </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> </a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li><a href=""> </a></li>
            <li><a href=""> </a></li>
            <li><a href=""> </a></li>
            <li><a href=""> </a></li>
            <li><a href=""> </a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
          <form method="POST" class="form" id="fm3">
                <h3>Output Data for Basic Input</h3>

                <div id="example1" class="hot handsontable"></div>
                <script>
                  //alert('{{ (tps[i]) }}');
                  //var xyz = '{{ (tps[0]) }}';
                  //var xxx = parseFloat('{{ (stemp) }}');
                  var yyy = parseFloat('{{ (stp1) }}');
                  //var zzz = parseFloat('{{ (incr1) }}');
                  var i = '{{ (i) }}';

                   var
                    data = [

                    ],
                    container = document.getElementById('example1'),
                    hot1;

                   for( i ; i < yyy; i++) {
                       //alert(i);
                       //alert('{{ (tps[i]) }}');
                       var t = '{{ (tps[i]) }}';
                       data.push(
                           {temp:t, press:999 } );
                        //xyz = '{{ (tps[0 + 1]) }}';
                       for(t;t<yyy;t++)
                          t = '{{ (tps[i+1]) }}'
                    }



                  function isEmptyRow(instance, row) {
                    var rowData = instance.getData()[row];

                    for (var i = 0, ilen = rowData.length; i < ilen; i++) {
                      if (rowData[i] !== null) {
                        return false;
                      }
                    }

                    return true;
                  }

                  function defaultValueRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
                    var args = arguments;

                    if (args[5] === null && isEmptyRow(instance, row)) {
                      td.style.color = '#999';
                    }
                    else {
                      td.style.color = '';
                    }
                    Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, args);
                  }

                  hot1 = new Handsontable(container, {
                    //startRows: 5,
                    //startCols: 99999,
                    minSpareRows: 1,
                    contextMenu: true,
                    width: 1000,
                    height: 500,
                    stretchH: 'all',
                    rowHeaders: true,
                    colHeaders: [
                        'Temperature (◦F)',
                        'Pressure (psia)',
                        'Bubble Point (psia)',
                        'Gas Oil Ratio (scf/STB)',
                        'Oil Density (lb/ft'+'3'.sup()+')',
                        'Oil Viscosity (cP)',
                        'Oil FVF (RB/STB)',
                        'Oil Compressibility (1/psi)',
                        'Gas Density (lb/ft'+'3'.sup()+')',
                        'Gas Viscosity (cP)',
                        'Gas FVF (ft'+'3'.sup()+'/scf)',
                        'Z Factor',
                        'Water Density (lb/ft'+'3'.sup()+')',
                        'Water Viscosity (cP)',
                        'Water FVF (RB/STB)',
                        'Water Compressibility (1/psi)',
                        'Oil/Gas IFT (dyne/cm)',
                        'Oil/Water IFT (dyne/cm)',
                    ],
                    columns: [
                        {
                            data: 'temp',
                            type: 'numeric',
                            format: '0.00'
                            //width: 20
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'press',
                            type: 'numeric',
                            format: '0.00'
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'pb',
                            type: 'numeric',
                            format: '0.00'
                            //width: 20
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'gor',
                            type: 'numeric',
                            format: '0.00'
                            //width: 20
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'po',
                            type: 'numeric',
                            format: '0.00'
                            //width: 20
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'uo',
                            type: 'numeric',
                            format: '0.00'
                            //width: 20
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'bo',
                            type: 'numeric',
                            format: '0.00'
                            //width: 20
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'co',
                            type: 'text'
                            //width: 20
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'pg',
                            type: 'numeric',
                            format: '0.00'
                            //width: 20
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'ug',
                            type: 'numeric',
                            format: '0.00'
                            //width: 20
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'bg',
                            type: 'numeric',
                            format: '0.00'
                            //width: 20
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'zf',
                            type: 'numeric',
                            format: '0.00'
                            //width: 20
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'pw',
                            type: 'numeric',
                            format: '0.00'
                            //width: 20
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'uw',
                            type: 'numeric',
                            format: '0.00'
                            //width: 20
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'bw',
                            type: 'numeric',
                            format: '0.00'
                            //width: 20
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'cw',
                            type: 'text'
                            //width: 20
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'iog',
                            type: 'numeric',
                            format: '0.00'
                            //width: 20
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'iow',
                            type: 'numeric',
                            format: '0.00'
                            //width: 20
                        },
                    ],
                  });

                  hot1.loadData(data);
                  function aa()
                  {

                  }

                </script>

                <br/>
                <footer class="footer">
                <p>Copyright © Invigour Energy 2016</p>
                </footer>
            </form>

        </div>

        </div>
      </div>
  </div>


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Just to make our placeholder images work. Don't actually copy the next line! -->
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/vendor/holder.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please guide me.Thanks.

Comment: Please read the code and you can see what did i declare as array, the array inside is a values which are obtain from user input using NumPy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a closer look at this javascript code you wrote:

```
for( i ; i < yyy; i++) {
    //alert(i);
    //alert('{{ (tps[i]) }}'):
    var t = '{{ (tps[i]) }}';
    data.push(
          {temp:t, press:999 } );
     //xyz = '{{ (tps[0 + 1]) }}';
     for(t;t<yyy;t++)
           t = '{{ (tps[i+1]) }}'
  }
```

Do you see the problem here? You're probably thinking youre incrementing your `i`, but there are two `i` s and they are quite bit different. The `i` in `tps[i]` gets evaluted by jinja on the server. The `i` in the javascript for loop gets evaluated the browser on the client. Jinja will evaluate tps at i and hard codes that in the javascript code.

If you want to send a python array to your javascript, here are two ways. You can write the whole array at once like this:

```
var tps_array = JSON.parse('{{ tps | safe }}');
```

and then iterate the array with javascript.

Alternatively, you can write a route that returns your list, and ajax that route on your page load to get the array. That way if the array is huge, your page will not take forever to load.

Comment: Thanks, JSON.parse really helpful!

Comment: Glad I could help. If you do parse json on the client, make sure to convert your tps array to a json string in your controller as well by `render_template (..., tps=json.dumps(tps), ...)`.

Comment: do you maybe know how to pass variable in one wtform to another wtform?

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry.